# Zathura pdf viewer Go back after following an internal link

Tags: zathura

I follow the link to the Appendix in my document, and I want to back to the previous spot of the document. How can I do this in Zathura pdf reader?

I cannot find a hotkey defined in the man page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably need to use

```
  ^o, ^i Move backward and forward through the jump list
```

where `^o` means <kbd>control-o</kbd>.